# Map not showing anything (just blank) on click

Tags: java, android, google-maps, maps

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
 import android.location.Location;
 import android.location.LocationListener;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class Map extends FragmentActivity {

 Cursor c;
MyDataBase mdb;
ArrayList<String> stop;




 GoogleMap gmaps;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.map);
mdb=new MyDataBase(this);
mdb.open();
double[] latitude=new double[97];
double[] longitude=new double[97];
stop=new ArrayList<String>();
Intent intent=getIntent();
stop=intent.getStringArrayListExtra("stopslist");
for(int i=0;i<stop.size();i++)
{
c=mdb.getStops(stop.get(i));
while(c.moveToNext())
{
    latitude[i]=c.getDouble(2);
    longitude[i]=c.getDouble(3);
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),latitude[i]+"  "+longitude[i], 1).show();  

}
}

SupportMapFragment map = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
gmaps=map.getMap();
gmaps.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
LatLng ll=new LatLng(latitude[0], longitude[0]);
 gmaps.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ll));
 gmaps.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));

for(int i=0;i<stop.size();i++)
{ 
   ll=new LatLng(latitude[i],longitude[i]);
   gmaps.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
   .title(stop.get(i))
   .snippet(stop.get(i)+" "+"Metro Station")
   .position(ll));
 }

 }
```

This is the code I have written to pin markers on the Map, but when I press the button, it goes to google maps and remains blank. Can Someone tell what is the problem here.?

Comment: Have you signed your apk with the keystore?

Comment: I have not published it yet. I am just testing for now..

Comment: even though, if you do not publish also, you have to sign your apk and then install

Comment: because you have registered your package in google api console with that keystore sha1 key

Answer (score 0):

Please make that you are using a right API key for the map generated through Google cloud console and if it still doesn't work then you have to

1. Sign your app with your keystore
2. Get SHA1 fingerprint with your keystore (not use debug.keystore)
3. Get API key for that keystore.
4. Replace this key in your code.
5. Sign and Run apk again.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you in this case, I would:

1. Recreate The API key, you follow this blog post for doing that, make sure you complete all the steps completely: [Google Maps API V2 Key](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403)
2. Don't forget to completely remove you application from the device before you install a version with the new key as the Google Maps API V2 key is getting cached until you remove the application.
3. If that didn't help you then try to remove the `debug.keystore` folder, compile any project in eclipse to recreate it and run this process all over again.